# Left Join with conditions and aggregate MAX using Spark Python / PySpark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

**What I have :** 2 massive spark dataframes, but here are some samples

- Dataframe A:

| ID | IG | OpenDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P111 | 100 | 13/04/2022 |
| P222 | 101 | 16/04/2022 |
| P333 | 102 | 20/04/2022 |

- Dataframe B:

| IG | Service | Dt_Service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 12/04/2022 |
| 100 | B | 13/04/2022 |
| 100 | B | 14/04/2022 |
| 101 | A | 15/04/2022 |
| 101 | A | 16/04/2022 |
| 101 | B | 17/04/2022 |
| 101 | B | 18/04/2022 |
| 102 | A | 19/04/2022 |
| 102 | B | 20/04/2022 |

**What I want:** I want to left join on dataframe A the two columns 'Service' and 'Dt_Service' using the key 'IG' but also having the Max value of 'Service' with the corresponding date. So I need the most recent 'Service' with its corresponding date for each row in Dataframe A. This is the result I expect :

| ID | IG | OpenDate | Service | Dt_Service |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P111 | 100 | 13/04/2022 | B | 14/04/2022 |
| P222 | 101 | 16/04/2022 | B | 18/04/2022 |
| P333 | 102 | 20/04/2022 | B | 20/04/2022 |

**Tool** : Spark 2.2 with PySpark since I am working on hadoop

Thank you for your help

Comment: can you do an aggregate on dataframe b and then join? a window function could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As samkart said we can do rank/row_number to get last service first then join to get your desired result

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
from pyspark.sql import Window
se="IG string,Service string,Dt_Service string"
de=[("100","A","2022-04-12"),("100","B","2022-04-13"),("100","B","2022-04-14"),("101","A","2022-04-15"),("101","A","2022-04-16"),("101","B","2022-04-17"),("101","B","2022-04-18"),("102","A","2022-04-19"),("102","B","2022-04-20")]

df1=spark.createDataFrame([("P111","100","13/04/2022"),("P222","101","16/04/2022"),("P333","102","20/04/2022")],"ID string,IG string, OpenDate string")
df2=fd.withColumn("rn",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("ig").orderBy(F.to_date(F.col("Dt_service")).desc()))).filter("rn==1").drop("rn")
df1.join(df2,"IG","inner").show()

#output
+---+----+----------+-------+----------+
| IG|  ID|  OpenDate|Service|Dt_Service|
+---+----+----------+-------+----------+
|100|P111|13/04/2022|      B|2022-04-14|
|101|P222|16/04/2022|      B|2022-04-18|
|102|P333|20/04/2022|      B|2022-04-20|
+---+----+----------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: ok, it is clear to me now. Thank you for taking the time to answer

Comment: You can accept the answer if this is what you were looking for